# why cant i reference a struct in the same struct type

Tags: swift, retain-cycle

I have a struct the has a property of the same type.
I'm getting an error

> Value type '' cannot have a stored property that references itself

But this is not a reference to self.
It's just a reference to a value of the same type.

If i change it to a class everything works (i need it to be a struct)

code:

```
public struct MockData {
    var data1: Int!
    var data2: String!
    var data3: MockData?
}
```

Why is this not compiling, what is the problem?

Thanks

Comment: Code which does not compile and run cannot have retain cycles. structs are value types and cannot have references.

Comment: @MartinR I don't think you choose a good dup target. This question have nothing to do with retrain/reference cycle. It is more about recursive struct with impossible to calculate size.

Comment: @MartinR can you explain what do you mean by this : " structs are value types and cannot have references"

Comment: @BryanChen: The accepted answer explains: *"When capturing and storing value types (structs and enums), there is no such thing as a reference. ..."* Another answer offers a solution (indirect enums).

Comment: @MartinR I think a good answer (at least the one I was writing) should mention that struct must have compile-time calculable size. In this case, `MockData` have a member of an `Optional`, which is also a struct, that holding a member of `MockData`, making the struct size not possible to be calculated.

Comment: thanks @BryanChen now i understand the problem.

Comment: Here is another one: [Swift struct type recursion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36080491/swift-struct-type-recursion). Or this one [Swift struct type recursive value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38785551/swift-struct-type-recursive-value).

Comment: It does answer the struct part, but maybe confusing if people think `Optional` is kind of a pointer rather than a struct.

Comment: @BryanChen and MartinR i didn't know that a struct size needs to be calculated on compile time. thanks

Comment: Also related: [Structs that refer to each other in Swift 3](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40771706/2976878) – another solution would be to create your own wrapper type to provide indirection.